# How do I type an array of functions that take an inferred tuple of their return types as an argument?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I have a function that takes an array of functions.
The main function runs each of them in turn, adding their awaited results to an array as it goes. The main function then returns that array/tuple.
Each of the functions in the array can return whatever type.
However, each function takes the 'result' array as an argument.

The function works fine, but I'm struggling with adding types, and wondered if there are any tricks I'm missing.

```js
type QuestionFunc<T> = (results: any[]) => Promise<T>;

type TupleFromQuestionFuncs<T extends QuestionFunc<any>[]> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends QuestionFunc<infer U> ? U : never;
};

const run = async <T extends QuestionFunc<any>[]>(
  questionFuncs: [...T]
): Promise<TupleFromQuestionFuncs<T>> => {
  const results: any[] = [];
  for (const questionFunc of questionFuncs) {
    results.push(await questionFunc(results));
  }
  return results as TupleFromQuestionFuncs<T>;
};

const result = await run([
  async (results) => 42,    // 'results' type: any[]
  async (results) => 'foo', // 'results' type: any[]
  async (results) => true   // 'results' type: any[]
]);
result; // type: [number, string, boolean]
console.log(result); // Output: [ 42, 'foo', true ]
```

As you can see, I have it inferring the return types for each function in the array, and using that as the return type.
What I'm struggling to figure out is how to set the type for the 'results' argument in the QuestionFunc functions.

Ideally, it would be the type for what is in results when that function gets called (the return types of the proceeding QuestionFunc functions), like so:

```js
const result = await run([
  async (results) => 42,    // 'results' type: []
  async (results) => 'foo', // 'results' type: [number]
  async (results) => true   // 'results' type: [number, string]
]);
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can certainly write the types but you're not going to get inference to work how you want, since each element of the array will depend on the type of the array itself, and TS's inference algorithm doesn't like doing contextual param typing and generic arg inference simultaneously. Do you need inference? If so, could you consider breaking this into a chain of methods instead of a single variadic method?